# jQuery syntax question : ul as variable, remove item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax, css-selectors

This is a simple syntax question.

I have a ul saved as a variable like this:

```
$list = $("#city_list");
```

I am later removing some items from the list with this code:

```
$('ul#city_list li#city_' + $id).remove();
```

How can I do that using the $list variable I created earlier so that I get something like this:

```
$list.('li#city_' + $id).remove();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [find](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/find)

```
$list.find('li#city_' + $id).remove();
```

> Never prefix an ID with a tag name

. So change your code to

```
$list.find('#city_' + $id).remove();
```

Read

[jQuery performance Rules](http://www.artzstudio.com/2009/04/jquery-performance-rules/#use-tags-before-classes)

Comment: Good point about id's.  An id is always supposed to be unique, so it's the only thing you need for selection.  You can't get any more specific than that.

Comment: jQuery would optimise this for you behind the scenes anyway... But still, it's a good rule to follow.